# How to build JSON data from CLDR data using the java conversion tool?

Tags: java, json, localization, internationalization, cldr

CLDR releases 23 through 24 include a tool for converting the XML data to JSON. The documentation on these tools is pretty much non-existant. I need to convert all of the XML data to JSON. How can I do that?

What I have tried so far:

1. I downloaded the `tools.zip` from http://unicode.org/Public/cldr/23.1/, extracted it, opened Terminal at the `tools/java` directory. Then I read the instructions in `tools/java/readme.txt`.
2. I built the tools using `ant clean all`
3. I tried to run the JSON tool using: `java org.unicode.cldr.json.Ldml2JsonConverter` - but that results in an error being thrown:

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/unicode/cldr/json/Ldml2JsonConverter
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.unicode.cldr.json.Ldml2JsonConverter
     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
   ```

Perhaps I am just doing something totally wrong, because I don't know much anything about Java. I need to get the JSON for my node.js project.

Answer (score 0):

probably a better Q for the cldr list.. you will need to start with

`ant jar
java -DCLDR_DIR=/path/to/cldr -jar cldr.jar org.unicode.cldr.json.Ldml2JsonConverter -h`

the "-h" will give options to the tool and /path/to/cldr shold be a path containing common and main